# How to speed up writing to file

Tags: fwrite

In a Gnuradio block, I have a trigger that is supposed to begin writing data to a file for a certain interval. In the "work" function the writing part occurs in this code:

```
if(counter!=0){
    ...
    if(trigger==1){
        counter = num_of_samples;
        of = fopen(filename,"ab");
        setbuf(of,buffer);
    }
    ...
}else{//Write to file occurs here.
    fwrite(i0,sizeof(float),1,of);
    fwrite(q0,sizeof(float),1,of);
    fwrite(i1,sizeof(float),1,of);
    fwrite(q1,sizeof(float),1,of);
    counter --;
    if(counter == 0){
        fflush(of);
        fclose(of);
    }
}
```

With the intent being that for "num_of_samples" amount of times, the 4 float inputs get written in binary to the end of some file specified by "filename".

This works as is, but the problem is for a large amount of data(say 200 MB) this process takes around 10 minutes for all the writes to complete. If I am writing a small amount of data, like 300 samples, it occurs quickly, so I think the issue is occuring during the "else" part of the code, since that is what is running when the larger loop is running.

I know that there is a way to write faster than this, because when using the "file_sink" block in Gnuradio, which uses the same fwrite function, it can write large amounts of data near instantaneously. But for some reason this code is much slower.(There is a "tagged_file_sink" block that basically does what this code should do, but it has a bug that is making it unusable for me, so I  need to write my own).

Is there a faster way I can write data to a file?

Comment: Are you saying the `else` block takes 10 minutes to complete? Or are you saying the whole logic takes 10 minutes?

Comment: The signature of `fwrite()` is `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`. That means you are telling `fwrite()` that your member is `1` bit and you are writing `sizeof(float)` numbers of members. It should be the other way around.

Comment: @alvits I am saying that if I have a stream incoming of a large amount of samples, like around 1 second of data at 10 Msps, it takes 10 minutes to write all of that, even though there are stream blocks that can write data almost instantaneously with the same "fwrite". But after the 'trigger' goes high, only the else block is being run for most of the execution.

Comment: @altvits Thanks for pointing that out. I've switched the 2nd and 3rd inputs to the function, but the performance seems about the same. Still roughly 10 minutes for the write.

Comment: How big is `buffer`? Can you show the definition of `buffer`?

Comment: If the `buffer` is shorter than `char [BUFSIZE]`, then it's a buffer overrun.

Comment: I just use a malloc with (FLOATS_PER_SAMPLE*sizeof(float)*NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES), and Im not getting any overflow messages in the Gnuradio terminal

Comment: `sizeof(float)*NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES)` is not guaranteed to be enough. The actual implementation of `setbuf(of,buffer)` is `setvbuf(of, buffer, buffer ? _IOFBF : _IONBF, BUFSIZ)`. Try using `setbuffer(of, buffer,sizeof(float)*NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES)`, instead.